# GCP: can we use output of one GSUTIL command embedded in other GSUTIL command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have a requirement where have a file in GCS and I need to remove the header and trailer of a file and load the data into other GCS bucket.

I have tried using something like this, but its not working.

```
gsutil cp `gsutil cat gs://<bucket>/<object> | sed '1,1d; $d'` gs://<target_bucket>/<target_object>
```

Can someone share your thoughts, if you have any other better way to achieve this?

Comment: I do not recommend your strategy. A command failure might result in uploading garbage. Put your command into a multiline script that checks for errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this format (the - as a file stream source)

```
gcloud storage cat gs://<bucket>/<object> | sed '1,1d; $d' | gcloud storage cp - gs://<target_bucket>/<target_object>
```

Comment: thats works like a charm, thanks

Comment: When my file size is > than 200mb, my airflow job is failing without throwing any error message.. not sure, does it cause any memory issue.. any suggestions?

Comment: Never ever run processing/transformation in Airflow. Airflow is an orchestrator, it should only trigger external processing. My advice is to put your code in a container, and run it on Cloud Run Jobs for instance.